# greenDAO queryBuilder with join

Tags: android, sql, greendao

I have 2 entities (person, lease). I want to get all person and lease attributes where `person_id` is equal to `Lease_personId`.

With a raw query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
INNER JOIN lease ON person._id = lease.person_id
```

on the database, everything works fine.

But with the greenDAO queryBuilder:

```
QueryBuilder<Person> queryBuilder = personDao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.join(Lease.class, LeaseDao.Properties.PersonId);

List <Person> persons = queryBuilder.list();
```

I get nothing back.

Answer (score 3):

Look like you are missing `where` condition. Below is what I found in documentation code

```
QueryBuilder<User> queryBuilder = userDao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.join(Address.class, AddressDao.Properties.userId)
  .where(AddressDao.Properties.Street.eq("Sesame Street"));
List<User> users = queryBuilder.list();
```

for more visit [greenDao Joins](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/joins/)

Comment: I had tried it with a where clause but it doesnt worked.